# Finding substring from input

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
+-----------+------+
| num       | valu |
+-----------+------+
|        93 | 0.43 |
|      9370 | 0.43 |
|      9375 | 0.43 |
|      9377 | 0.43 |
|      9378 | 0.43 |
|      9379 | 0.43 |
|      89789| 0.1  |
|      789  | 0.2  |
|      39789| 0.1  |
+-----------+------+
```

I could not find the right query that does the following:
if my input is 937089 then row 2, which contains the first 4 numbers of the input, should be returned.  The sub-string should be the beginning of the input.

Your help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: you mean you want get only first 4 numbers from every input value ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple thing and didn't show any effort

Comment: It may have been a simple thing but I could not get the right query and needed it little urgently and could not do detail research.

Comment: echo_me and Khalid thanks for the response.  But the answer below from fthiella is what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE '937089' LIKE CONCAT(num, '%')
```

Comment: This fails when num is `937089XYZ` and input is just `937089`.

Comment: Atleast in my case it will work because num will always be a substring of the input.

Comment: but you said you want get only 4 numbers this solution will not give you 4 numbers from all integers